# Lollipop update - Where did my active display setting go?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, moto-x

I have a 1st gen Moto X (2013, Verizon). I received the lollipop update (5.1) and I want to change the notifications on active display. I don't see this setting anywhere.

How can I change my active display settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the moto app. It looks like a rainbow colored star.
On the top right, tap the gear.
On the bottom right will be the display settings.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: That's it! Would never have thought to look in a place other than settings.

Comment: @Jeff Motorola likes to keep things close to stock android, so having it in the app works better for that.